# How do I get certain message from a curl response?

Tags: php

So i have a curl that returns this response.

```
 {"creditCards":[{"type":"CreditCard","nonce":"tokencc_bd_v3vyfk_7r75rw_vcprsv_yds997_9gz","description":"ending in 00","consumed":false,"threeDSecureInfo":null,"details":{"bin":"434769","lastTwo":"00","lastFour":"1100","cardType":"Unknown"},"binData":{"prepaid":"No","healthcare":"Unknown","debit":"Yes","durbinRegulated":"Unknown","commercial":"Unknown","payroll":"Unknown","issuingBank":"Unknown","countryOfIssuance":"USA","productId":"Unknown"}}]}
```

How ever I only want to echo (tokencc_bc_pyp7yn_vgdr5x_rr6rj8_zntbj5_n45) to be clean

I have already tried this code but it doesnt work

```
function GetStr($string, $start, $end)
{
    $str = explode($start, $string);
    $str = explode($end, $str[1]);
    return $str[0];
}

$message = trim(strip_tags(getstr($curl,'nonce": "','"')));
echo"$message";
```

Comment: Assume `$string` is the return from curl; `echo json_decode($string)->message;`

Comment: Okay that works for my curl1 but for the returned string of curl 2 /**/callback_json7130933127f843d3b1aac141ada5e52b({"creditCards":[{"type":"CreditCard","nonce":"tokencc_bc_tc5n2d_hh8zc8_2bnqkb_kfqt5z_597","description":"","consumed":false,"threeDSecureInfo":null,"details":{"bin":"","lastTwo":"","lastFour":"","cardType":"Unknown"},"binData":{"prepaid":"Unknown","healthcare":"Unknown","debit":"Unknown","durbinRegulated":"Unknown","commercial":"Unknown","payroll":"Unknown","issuingBank":"Unknown","countryOfIssuance":"Unknown","productId":"Unknown"}}],"status":202})

Comment: I want to get this tokencc_bc_tc5n2d_hh8zc8_2bnqkb_kfqt5z_597 but it doesnt work as  echo json_decode($string)->nonce;

Comment: Update your question with that code, hard to read in comment.

Comment: I've edited it check it please

Comment: You are getting that exact string from a CURL request? it's not valid JSON.

Comment: Is there a way I can get the certain text I want? Yes that is the response

Comment: You can't get the text you want easily without it being valid JSON. You could try `json_decode($string)->creditCards[0]->nonce` but I doubt it will work

Comment: did'nt work I dont know but it is the reponse I am getting

Comment: Hello would it be a valid json if this string would be removed? /**/callback_json7130933127f843d3b1aac141ada5e52b

Comment: Yes, if that was removed along with the parenthesis.

Comment: then is there a  php command that removes the first 48 characters? then using json_decode to get the string?

Comment: What API are you using that returns this data? It would be better to just fix it there...

Comment: I have removed the callback thing but still I cannot get the nonce

Comment: As I said before, you also have to remove the parenthesis at the beginning and end.

Comment: Yes I have removed it on the beginning and in the end making the code like this (check edited post)

Comment: With that exact output, you would access it with `json_decode($string)->creditCards[0]->nonce`

Comment: And that worked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

$message will be json, so you'll need to first use json_decode on the result.

Then in order to access 'message' you would do this just as you would any other object.

```
$message = json_decode($message);
echo $message->message;
```